# Is read-write lock needed for this use-case

Tags: c++, multithreading, readwritelock

My question is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225223/do-i-need-to-protect-this-variable-with-a-lock), however I am sure if the conclusion drawn in the given thread applies here.

My use case:
In the application, there is a status thread which sends out the same texual information after every 1 second. Texual information contains the application group name. This status is used by status reader to determine if application server is on/off.

Now application group name can change during it's life time. It is ensured that only single thread in the application triggers this event due to some user activity. Now this single thread has the new application group name which I need to update to my status thread.

My current implementation is as follows

1. Status Thread Main()
   Take ReadLock
   Read the application group name
   Release the ReadLock

   send the status
2. Updater Thread Main()
   Taken write Lock
   Update the group name
   Release the WriteLock

However, due to large number of updates to be sent I fear that I might introduce performance degration for heavy load. So I am working on following implementation, but I am not sure if this would work.

New proposed implementation is

1. Sender Thread holds char* ptr, char[1024] primaryData, char[1024] secondaryData.
2. When first time application is started, group name is updated in primaryData and ptr points to primaryData.
3. Whenever update thread has update event, it will
   Check if (ptr == primaryData)
       Copy new application name to secondaryData
           ptr = secondaryData
   else
       Copy new application name to primaryData.
       ptr = primaryData
4. Status thread will always use data pointed by ptr to send the status. Status Thread will eventually receive updated ptr (considering cache coherency) and will start transmitting new data.

Few points to be considered over here.
1. It's ok even if new data is not instantly available to Status thread
2. I dont want program crash due to invalid memory access.

Friends, could you please tell me if above logic would help me to avoid read-write lock.

Comment: You should start with your current implementation and optimize AFTER you notice performance degradation.  Premature optimization is (almost) always a bad thing :)

Comment: @pwny I agree. But even during load test, I would not be able to generate actual production quality load. So I want to avoid non-optimized coding..

Comment: @AmeyJah: Then your load testing is flawed. It should be able to produce loads that are *higher* than anything you're likely to see in production.

Answer (score 1):

> could you please tell me if above logic would help me to avoid read-write lock.

No, this logic will not let you avoid locking. The proposed scheme is full of race conditions.

My advice would be to use a single `char` array and a single mutex shared by the status and update threads. This will lead to very simple logic that will be easy to get right.

If -- and only if -- it turns out that this leads to unacceptable lock contention you should consider optimizing further.

Answer (score 1):

A read-write lock in a scenario with a single reader and a single writer is no different than a plain old mutex. Just use a mutex.